# jQuery: Sort a table column not rows

Tags: jquery, sorting

I want to sort a table by column's head field. Means I want to keep the rows at same place but order of columns should be sort based on column heading field(td).

For Example:

**table before sorting:**

```
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
assign1|assign3|assign2|assign4|
```

**and after sorting:**

```
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
assign1|assign2|assign3|assign4|
```

---

@seth
I have to sort(change order) of columns with headers.

@CMS
I have tried tablesorter plugin and this plugin sort rows. Means it changes the order of rows in ascending or descending order.

But my problem is different I have to change the order of columns with their header cell in ascending or descending order.

please look at my example in question.

Comment: will the header text be the same as its column cells?  Or will the text in the cells be different yet the sort should only be based on the headers?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's something I whipped up.  It's not the most elegant or cleanest probably but it works.

```
// sorting function for the headers
function th_sorter(a, b) {
   // just compare the text
   var cmp = $(a).text() > $(b).text();
   if (cmp) {
     return 1;
   }
   else {
     return $(a).text() === $(b).text() ? -1 : 0;
   }
}

var sorted = [], temp=[];
// first sort the 1st row so we can figure out what goes where
$('table tr:first').each(
  function(i, tr) {
      $(tr).children('td').each( function(idx,node) {
        $(node).data('orig', idx);
      }).sort( th_sorter ).each( function(idx, node) {
        sorted.push( { 
            html: $(node).html(), 
            idx: $(node).data('orig') 
          } );
      });
});

// now re-arrange the deck chairs
$('table tr').each( function(i, tr) {
  // double each, once to capture and once to move                                          
  $(tr).children('td').each( function( idx, node) {
    temp[idx] = $(node).html();
  }).each( function(idx,node) {
    $(node).html( temp[ sorted[idx].idx ] );
  });
  temp = [];
});
```

[Demo page](http://jsbin.com/uyici)

Comment: Just used this solution and it worked perfectly for me.  Huge, huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to this plugin:

- [jQuery.Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)